# How to make a Visual Studio C++ project structure match the file system structure?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, project-structure

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 Professional. In my entire experience with Visual Studio (since version 6), a C++ project structure was always virtual. In other words, when I move files around and create folders in the project, this had no bearing on the actual structure on the filesystem. I've always had to manage the two independently (the filesystem structure and the project structure).

Is there a way to make C++ project structure in Visual Studio act as it does in C#, whereby all move/copy/create folder/etc operations in a C++ project directly affect the corresponding file system hierarchy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just click the "Show All Files" button in the solution explorer, and there you go ;) This is not a new feature; it's been around for a long time, as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible, since Visual C++ and Visual C# handle "folders" quite differently.

In Visual C++, folders are more akin to filters, for example a "Source Files" folder might be hinted as a filter to contain .cpp files, while a "Header Files" will contain .h files.

However there's a workaround, described here : [Visual Studio projects with multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645062/visual-studio-projects-with-multiple-folders)

Comment: I guess this is the painful truth. Thanks for the help.